# using sed delimiter when changing a line

Tags: replace, sed, delimiter

I used the following to change a line in a file:

```
sed -i '\%oldword% c\ newline' filename
```

I know how to change the delimiter for the `oldword`. But there are also backslash symbols inside the newline. Is there a way to change the delimiter for the newline content so that I can escape backslash symbols?

An example that involving backslash escape replacing `local_address` text in file with `root/usr/dict2/file`

to make it work I need to escape all the backslashes

```
sed -i '\%local_address% c\ //root//usr//dict2//file' file
```

Is there a neat way to do this?

Comment: consider changing to post from a verbal description of your problem to an simple coded example of your problem (with error messagess), that we can copy/paste to our local cmd-line. Good luck.

Comment: I updated an example.

Comment: why aren't you using the `s@original_String@newString@` form of sed substitution? Good luck.

Comment: I need to replace a line, and I only know the first few strings of the line. So I have to change the line.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\%oldword%c\line\
line two with a \\ in it\
line three\
line four' file
```

Use a `\\` to include a `\` within a `c`, `a` or `i` command.